# Clickable parts in editable text in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

What is the best approach in Jetpack Compose when I want text to be completely editable but also want some parts of it to be clickable?

I could use TextField. But is there a way to make some parts of it clickable? And furthermore I would also like to style the text by using AnnotatedString.

I could use ClickableText and make it somewhat editable. But I would also like to select some text while editing. This seems to be harder, on the first glance.

Or should I use none of them?

Comment: Did you try any of the approaches?

Comment: Honestly, I'm a bit in the dark. I'm not sure if there is a simple solution that I'm not aware of. What came next to my mind was something like using the letters' positions returned by ClickableText to draw a cursor while directly editing the string. Something like faking a TextField. But this seemed to me pretty hacky. So the more correct way would probably be to have a serious look at both libraries' source code. Sorry, as I said, I'm really unsure about the direction.